# bash + how to delete the strings that defined in var2 from var2

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, awk, sed

I use in my bash script the following variables - val1 ,val2

val1 represented all disks that should be  in OS linux

val2 represented the current disks in OS linux

my target is to delete the disks "$val2" from "$val1" variable

```
val1="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk"
val2="sdb sdc sdf sdd sde sdg"
```

expected results:

```
val3=sdh sdi sdj sdk
```

and set the results as below in val3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **`sed`** substitution:

```
val3=$(sed -E 's/\<('"$(tr ' ' '|' <<<"$val2")"')\> *//g' <<<"$val1")
echo "$val3"
sdh sdi sdj sdk
```

---

- `$(tr ' ' '|' <<<"$val2")` - imitating regex alternation group, this will result in `sdb|sdc|sdf|sdd|sde|sdg`. The full construction should look as `\<(sdb|sdc|sdf|sdd|sde|sdg)\>`
- `\<` and `\>` - are word boundaries

Comment: you have a bug , example in case you set that val1="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk sdl sdm sdn"
val2="sdb sde sdf sdd"

then output will be 

sdcsdg sdh sdi sdj sdk sdl sdm sdn  ( no space between sdc to sdg )

Comment: @yael, so remove the 1st `" *"`. Or, alternatively, you may delete excessive spaces with additional `tr` command: `sed -E 's/\<('"$(tr ' ' '|' <<<"$val2")"')\>//g' <<<"$val1" | tr -s ' '`. That's all

Comment: can you please update your answer so all folks will be know about it

Comment: @yael, you should update your question with another input case at first

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
$ val1="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk"
$ val2="sdb sdc sdf sdd sde sdg"
$ comm -23 <(echo "$val1" | sed "s/ /\n/g" | sort) <(echo "$val2" | sed "s/ /\n/g"| sort) | paste -sd" "
sdh sdi sdj sdk
$
```

`echo "$val1" | sed "s/ /\n/g" | sort`  :Flatten the list of variables and sort
`comm -23` : Get the content unique to flattened val1
`paste -sd" "` : Concatenate the result using space

Answer (score 0):

command

---

```
echo $val1| tr " " "\n" > val1.txt; echo $val2| tr " " "\n"  > val2.txt; val3=`awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next}!($1 in a) {print $1}' val2.txt val1.txt` ;echo $val3
```

---

output

```
 echo $val3
sdh sdi sdj sdk
```

---

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` and [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

val1='sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk'
val2='sdb sdc sdf sdd sde sdg'

val3="$(grep -v -F -f <(printf "%s\n" $val2) <(printf "%s\n" $val1) | xargs)"

echo "$val1"
echo "$val2"
echo "$val3"
```

The process substitutions with `printf "%s\n"` are used to make the lists in `var1` and var2 appear to be files with one entry per line to `grep`.  `var2` is the input "file" to the `-f` option, and `var1` is the "file" to be grepped.   `xargs` is used to convert the output of the `grep` from multiple lines to a single space separated string...a lazy but useful trick.

And here's the same thing using arrays:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

val1=(sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk)
val2=(sdb sdc sdf sdd sde sdg)

val3=($(grep -vFf <(printf "%s\n" "${val2[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${val1[@]}")))

echo "${val1[@]}"
echo "${val2[@]}"
echo "${val3[@]}"
```